# Android ADT 21.0.0. Memory leaks in graphical layout

Tags: android, android-layout, memory-leaks, adt

I'm running ADT 21.0.0.v201210310015-519525  on eclipse 4.2.1 and each time I start working on graphical layout eclipse slowly starts to get unresponsive.
After opening ~5 files like this it is practically unusable and need to restart.

Anyone else got these issues?

I've set my .ini in eclipse to increased memory and java 1.6 like mentioned in some solutions but problem still persists.

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion = 1.6
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: I have this problem and I am looking for a solution

Comment: @breceivemail: Why Don't you try after Updating ADT to latest version?

Comment: Please see the link below:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15026097/2114308 is a good answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue and updated everything and the problem seems to be resolved now. I am running  Version: 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 in Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 2. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I had to upgrade both eclipse and ADT to the nightly build, as it addressed this problem

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this problem occurs when you try to load the very heavy layout in eclipse. 
by heavy layout I mean, if you are trying to load the heavy graphics in layout OR if you are trying to use custom control in your layout.

When you try to open your layout (visually) in eclipse it actually tries to compile and run the custom control classes and try to render the view.

as eclipse is having very less heap size this crashing issues occurs. I advice you to check this type of layout into emulator OR device rather then testing it on Eclipse i.e. just avoid loading of this type of layout and try to work in XML and run it in emulator.

Comment: I agree but it seems with new ADT everything works better. This issues stopped happening to me after update even with "heavy" layouts.

Comment: Good info here. I upgraded everything on my ADT and SDK and it would still crash in under a minute. Only happens in layouts with custom views. Very frustrating.